# Issue in compiling aloha in Omnetpp 5.6.2.& 5.6.1 in windows 10, 64 bit

Tags: installation, compilation, omnet++, aloha

I am trying to install OMNETpp5.6.2 but failed as it gave me compilation error aloha can not be compiled or  so,...
SO I tried with omnet 5.6.1 but ended up with same error as shown below

```
===== Compiling aloha ====

make[2]: Warning: File 'out/gcc-release//.last-copts' has modification time 1.4 s in the future

Host.cc

Server.cc

Creating executable: out/gcc-release//aloha.exe

ln: failed to create hard link 'aloha.exe' => 'out/gcc-release//aloha.exe': Operation not permitted

make[2]: *** [Makefile:87: aloha.exe] Error 1

make[1]: *** [Makefile:134: aloha] Error 2

make: *** [Makefile:28: allmodes] Error 2
```

I am installing it on other than C drive, could this be an issue?
OS - Windows 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following rules:

1. Take care that the name of directory of your OMNeT++ does not contain any space.
2. Temporary turn off real-time antivirus protection.

Answer (score 0):

The strange thing is that while you can create files in the output directory, the build process cannot create a hard link.

My guess is that the filesystem is probably FAT and not NTFS. The FAT filesystem does not support hard linking and OMNeT++ is NOT tested on FAT filesystems.

Solution: install it on an NTFS drive.